# How to change the value of an HTML element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener

I am creating a counter and i want to increase, decrease or reset 0. What should i to write in the event listener?

`<div class="display">0</div>`

I have tried with only the variable and with textContent also but neither works.

```
upBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  displayImage.textContent += 1;
});
```

```
downBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  displayImage -= 1;
});
```

Comment: You have not posted enough code for anyone to help. How does `displayImage` get its value (for example)? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: `displayImage.textContent` will be a string, so `+= 1` will likely append not add. Please add a text-based [mcve] showing the issue. Right now we can only make educated guesses

Comment: I think it would be better if you get the current number on your element with the `event listener`, convert it to number, add or subtract and then add the new value to the element with `textContent`